# link_to gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

In my `index.html.erb`

```
<p><%= link_to "log Out", :action => 'logout' %></p>
```

In home controller.rb

```
def logout
end
```

and gives me error

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"logout", :controller=>"home"}

this maybe simple question. I'm new to rails.

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if the route exists in routes.rb
I seems that you have added the action in controller but not added the route in routes.rb
An alternative to manually adding routes to routes.rb, you can run a command like this

```
rails g controller home log_out
```

Then keep the home_controller.rb file as it was.(Don't overwrite it). This command will add a route automatically in routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify route for 'logout' method in routes.rb

you can do it like this:

```
resource :home do
  collection do
   get 'logout'
  end
end
```

OR

you need to just add

```
  get 'home/logout'
```